# Special Characters in read.table() with unz()

Tags: r

I am working with importing a series of text files from many zipped folders.

Before, I was unzipping the files with WinRAR, then applying read.table as:

```
main <- read.table(file.path(dir, paste0("Current/17/Folder/Main.txt")),
                    sep = '|',
                    header = FALSE,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,             
                    skipNul = TRUE,    
                    comment.char="",  
                    quote = ""
)
```

Which worked, but required unzipping myself (which takes up a prohibitive amount of space). I stumbled on unz, which would allow me to avoid this step as follows:

```
main <- read.table(unz(file.path(dir, paste0("Current/17.zip")), "Folder/Main.txt"),
                    sep = '|',
                    header = FALSE,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,             
                    skipNul = TRUE,    
                    comment.char="",  
                    quote = ""
)
```

The latter works in most cases, but for some files, the read.table throws an error

```
number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns
```

I discerned that this is from some odd characters in the file. Comparing the two approaches in one case, I find that the manual unzip and read approach converts these special characters to "??" (with a white background, suggesting a foreign character) (which is desirable, if it cannot read them), whereas the second approach simply throws an error when it hits them (the ?? are not reported in the output), and does not read the rest of the current line or file. I looked at the line in question in Bash with:

```
sed -n '10905951 p' Main.txt
```

And it also reports the same "??" that show up in the read.table in R.

I have tried using fileEncoding, with a few different file formats, to no avail. Many other approaches I have seen for dealing with odd characters like this require manually replacing the characters, but I am struggling to even find out what the characters are, and why WinRAR's unzip converts them to something readable while unz does not. I have also considered other read options, but read.table is preferable to me because it allows for the skipNul option, which is relevant for my data.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What are `rows2load` and `colnames` and how are they defined?

Comment: Neither are relevant - I removed them from the example. One was just for testing loading only part of the file, the other was to apply column names from an external list.

Comment: Ok, cool.  Can you tell if there are any pipe characters in the data?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, do you have code that would test for that?

Comment: Well, i'm wondering if your delimiter of `|` is actually a character that appears in your data somewhere.  Let's say one of your records contained something like `$%|%` - your current read criteria would separate that into two fields `$%` and `%`, and could thus throw off the data structure.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not the problem, since the first read.table works fine, and would be subject to the same problem? Also I'm not sure pipes would ever show up as "??" characters?

Comment: yep you're right... hard to say, would need to see the data.

Comment: Possibly try a different implementation of an unzip function, `utils::unzip()` for instance?

Comment: Using unzip would require unzipping and reading separately, which is the main concern in terms of efficiency/space, but this is certainly the eventual route if no solution using unz can be found.